# checking number of uploads through javascript and php

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I want to check the number of uploads by the help of javascript.This is concerning multiple file uploads .I have to display an alert message if the number of uploads made are less than 5 on submission of the page.Can anybody help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden variable and increase the value of the hidden variable.